# Ambiguity using because

Tags: ambiguity

> Are you feeling hot because my lingerie is cool?

What is the speaker asking here?
Is the speaker offering advice to someone?
Or, perhaps the speaker is asking a question about the cause of a person’s condition.

Comment: A question is a question surely? How is the quoted question offering advice?

Comment: The person wants to know the cause of the condition and hence is using "because" to determine the cause.

Comment: It's a play on words. Feeling "hot" (meaning turned on) by lingerie that is "cool" (for lingerie to be "cool"/nice, it's likely sexy).

Comment: Mike (see his comment: play on words) has the right idea.

Comment: Is it hot in here, or is it just me?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you are thinking about "hot" and "cool" in their normal definitions relating to temperature.

You should recognize that this is not the intent of the sentence. A slang meaning should be applied to "hot" and "cool"

**Hot**

In this context you are referring to sexual excitement.

Another slang meaning relates to "superior"

eg. *He thinks he is so hot, but he isn't really!*

**Cool**

In this context being cool means looking fashionable, even sexy because of the garment that it refers to.

Another slang meaning would be "calm" "not excitable"

eg. *This business man is very cool when he is in a difficult negotiation*.

**Conclusion**

This sentence could be written this way without the use of slang

*Are you excited because my lingerie is so sexy?*

This is a woman talking because men don't wear "lingerie". She is flirting with probably a man but it could be a woman too, depending on her sexual persuasion.